# drf-spectacular: Add description to HTTP_204

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

```
@extend_schema(                                                                                                                    
    request=MyRequestSerializer,                                                                             
    responses={200: MyResponseSerializer(many=True),                                                         
               204: None,                                                                                    
               },                                                                                            
    examples=[                                                                                               
       OpenApiExample(                                                                                       
           '204',                                                                                            
           status_codes=['204'],                                                                             
           summary="My documentation summary",                                                               
           description="My documentation description",                                                       
          response_only=True,                                                                                
       ),                                                                                                    
   ....]                                                                                                     
)
```

This is what I have tried, but what I get is
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the new `drf-spectacular` version `0.15.1` added the `OpenApiResponse` feature. this snippet is from the test cases:

```
from drf_spectacular.utils import OpenApiResponse, extend_schema

@extend_schema(
    description='creation description', 
    responses={
        201: OpenApiResponse(response=int, description='creation with int response.'),
        204: OpenApiResponse(description='creation with no response.'),
        223: None,
})
```